# What is the correct IPs need to be allowed for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

We call Revit API and want to received the call back from Revit.
And  block other IPs  and  only allow IPs as:

1. 3.213.115.148
2. 3.212.238.83
3. 3.208.45.222

But we confirm the callback from different IPs  as 3.229.167.149 etc.
Could you tell me what is the correct IPs need to be allowed.
Thanks.

We see document about this.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you say call Revit API, I believe you mean Revit Design Automation APIs.

And you are checking the right documentation at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/restrictions/, but looks not the right section, from the section of "Design Automation API for Revit", the IPs need to be allow-listed for Revit DA should be as follow:

***In order to process “onComplete” or “onProgress” callback behind a firewall, the following IPs need to be allowed for Revit**:

- 3.229.167.149
- 44.207.230.78
- 54.175.193.194

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer.　but which documents where 3.229.167.149, 44.207.230.78,54.175.193.194 are writed.

Comment: please check the link above, I added the link,  but actually, it's just the link you are looking at..

Comment: I confirmed new IPs is updated in

Comment: thank you very much again. I confirmed new IPs is updated in the link page.  Could you tell me why IPs are changed at this time,  whether or not to change in the future, when to change, frequency of change, etc. thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confuse, this seems just released according to https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-aps-design-automation-firewall-rules